# How do I programatically turn off show pages in navigation for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, moss, spweb

I am progamatically creating a SharePoint site using

```
SPWeb spWeb = spSite.AllWebs.Add(...);
```

What code do I need run to set the spWeb to turn off the "Show pages in navigation" option?

**Answer:**

```
publishingWeb.IncludePagesInNavigation = false;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wasn't sure myself but I was able to locate [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507633.aspx):

> Modifying navigation is another common
>   branding task since it affects what
>   users can see and how they can proceed
>   through a site hierarchy. The
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing
>   namespace exposes several classes that
>   target the Publishing site
>   infrastructure, such as PublishingWeb
>   and PublishingPage. Using these
>   classes, we can easily modify
>   navigation for each site. If you want
>   a child Web to display as a root level
>   site in global navigation, first turn
>   off inheritance from the parent site,
>   like so:

```
publishingWeb.InheritGlobalNavigation = false;
```

> You might also want to hide all site
>   pages from global navigation. Setting
>   IncludePagesInNavigation to false
>   hides all pages in the site,
>   regardless of whether the
>   PublishingPage.IncludeInGlobalNavigation
>   property is set to true

```
// do not show pages in navigation
publishingWeb.IncludePagesInNavigation = false;
```

> If you are dealing with default sites
>   that don't inherit from PublishingWeb,
>   it's still possible to hide these
>   sites from the global navigation bar.
>   For example, if you create a site
>   collection using the collaboration
>   portal template and want to exclude
>   the News site from global navigation,
>   add that site to the
>   __GlobalNavigationExcludes property of the site:

```
string globalNavExcludes = String.Empty;
SPWeb webSite = MSDNSiteCollection.RootWeb;
// _GlobalNavigationExcludes property contains a delimited string of 
// GUIDs identifying the Id of each site to be excluded from global
// navigation

if (webSite.AllProperties.ContainsKey("__GlobalNavigationExcludes")) {
  globalNavExcludes = 
    webSite.AllProperties["__GlobalNavigationExcludes"].ToString();
}

SPWeb newsSite = MSDNSiteCollection.AllWebs["News"];
// string is delimited "{GUID};{GUID};",
// use format code B to convert to string
globalNavExcludes += String.Concat(currentWeb.ID.ToString("B"), ";");

webSite.AllProperties["__GlobalNavigationExcludes"] = globalNavExcludes;
webSite.Update();
```

> Adding navigation nodes directly to an
>   SPNavigationNodeCollection is a good
>   way to display only the nodes you want
>   as well as to group nodes and links to
>   external sites. Figure 10 shows how to
>   add an internal link, external link,
>   and a heading to the global navigation
>   bar. This example addresses some of
>   the properties of the SPNavigation
>   class that affect whether the link
>   opens in a new window and how to
>   handle empty URLs.

Answer (score 2):

For SP 2010 use below...

publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;